# Wrapping an ExpandoObject within a SafeExpandoObject

Tags: c#, json, dynamic-programming

I've written code to deserialize a JSON into an `ExpandoObject`. The only problem with the ExpandoObject is that if you try to access a member which doesn't exist, it throws an exception.

So I've written a wrapper for the ExpandoObject called `SafeExpandoObject` which basically implements a `DynamicObject` that encapsulates an `ExpandoObject` and when a member is accessed it returns a `SafeExpandoObject` wrapped response so that it can be recursively accessed without ever throwing an exception.

```
dynamic jsonMeta = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(jsonScript, new ExpandoObjectConverter());
jsonMeta = new SafeExpandoObject(jsonMetadata); // Rewrap the ExpandoObject in a SafeExpandoObject that doesn't throw exceptions when accessing unknown members
string x = jsonMeta?.a?.b?.c?.d ?? "defVal" // Access the values dynamically
```

The SafeExpandoObject has a method `TryMemberGet` which is called when a member on the object is accessed dynamically and `TryMemberSet` which is called when a value is assigned dynamically.

```
/// <summary>
/// A safe wrapper for an ExpandoObject that returns a null when trying to access an unknown member/property instead of throwing an exception
/// </summary>
public class SafeExpandoObject : DynamicObject
{

    private ExpandoObject _expandoObject;

    /// <summary>
    /// Default constructor, empty object
    /// </summary>
    public SafeExpandoObject()
    {
        _expandoObject = new ExpandoObject();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initialization for a safe expando object wrapper
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="originalExpandoObject">The original 'unsafe' ExpandoObject</param>
    public SafeExpandoObject(ExpandoObject originalExpandoObject)
    {
        _expandoObject = originalExpandoObject;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked when a member of the object is accessed
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="result">Set to a SafeExpandoObject/value if the member exists or null if it doesn't</param>
    /// <returns>true</returns>
    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        IDictionary<string, object> expandoDictionary = _expandoObject;

        if (expandoDictionary.ContainsKey(binder.Name))
        {
            dynamic dictObject = expandoDictionary[binder.Name];
            // Wrap the results of the dereference into a SafeExpandoObject so when a member is accessed again it come right back here
            result = CheckAndConvertToSafeExpando(dictObject);
            return true;
        }
        else // When we're accessing an unknown member return null but all mark the operation as success otherwise it'll throw an exception
        {
            result = null;
            return true; // Success
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates or replaces the property of a member in the object
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>True</returns>
    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
    {
        IDictionary<string, object> expandoDictionary = _expandoObject;

        expandoDictionary[binder.Name] = value;
        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Calls a method function assigned to the object
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="result">Result of the method invoked</param>
    /// <returns>true</returns>
    public override bool TryInvokeMember(InvokeMemberBinder binder, object[] args, out object result)
    {
        IDictionary<string, object> expandoDictionary = _expandoObject;
        dynamic method = expandoDictionary[binder.Name];
        result = method(args[0].ToString(), args[1].ToString());
        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Set the key and value on the object
    /// </summary>
    private void SetMember(string name, object value)
    {
        IDictionary<string, object> expandoDictionary = _expandoObject;
        expandoDictionary[name] = value;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Iteratively converts the object into a SafeExpandoObject
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="someObject">The object to the converted to a SafeExpandoObject</param>
    /// <returns>SafeExpandoObject</returns>
    private dynamic CheckAndConvertToSafeExpando(dynamic someObject)
    {
        // Iterate through the object looking for ExpandoObject and convert them to SafeExpandoObject
        if (someObject is ExpandoObject) // Check if it's an ExpandoObject
        {
            dynamic safeExpandoObject = new SafeExpandoObject();
            IDictionary<string, object> expandoDictionary = someObject as ExpandoObject;
            foreach (dynamic expandoKvp in expandoDictionary)
            {
                if (expandoKvp.Value is ExpandoObject) // If the property value is an ExpandoObject, recursively convert it
                    safeExpandoObject.SetMember(expandoKvp.Key, CheckAndConvertToSafeExpando(expandoKvp.Value));
                else if (expandoKvp.Value is IList) // If it's a list of items, convert them if needed
                {
                    dynamic expandoListItem = ((IList<dynamic>)expandoKvp.Value).Select(item => item).ToList(); // Make a shallow copy of the list so we don't mess with the original list, TODO: do we need a deep copy here since we will be creating new SafeExpandoObject for each item in the list?
                    for (int i = 0; i < expandoListItem.Count; i++) // Iterate through the list and update each item
                        expandoListItem[i] = CheckAndConvertToSafeExpando(expandoListItem[i]);
                    safeExpandoObject.SetMember(expandoKvp.Key, expandoListItem); // Finally copy the converted list to the new SafeExpandoObject
                }
                else
                    safeExpandoObject.SetMember(expandoKvp.Key, expandoKvp.Value); // Otherwise, copy the property directly
            }

            return safeExpandoObject; // Return the new SafeExpandoObject
        }
        else if (someObject is IList) // If it's a list then convert them if needed
        {
            dynamic safeExpandoListItem = ((IList<dynamic>)someObject).Select(item => item).ToList(); // Make a shallow copy of the list so we don't mess with the original list, TODO: do we need a deep copy here since we will be creating new SafeExpandoObject for each item in the list?
            for (int i = 0; i < safeExpandoListItem.Count; i++) // Iterate through the list and update each item
                safeExpandoListItem[i] = CheckAndConvertToSafeExpando(safeExpandoListItem[i]);
            return safeExpandoListItem; // Return the updated object
        }
        else
            return someObject; // Return the unmodified object
    }
}
```

So I have a few questions here:

## 1

Is the `CheckAndConvertToSafeExpando` method good? Its job is to recursively convert the `ExpandoObject` into a `SafeExpandoObject`. I can only foresee three types of objects within an ExpandoObject,

1. `ExpandoObject`
2. `IList<>`
3. Everything else is just a value which can't be dereferenced further, so keep as it

Is my assumption above correct?

## 2

In the `TryGetMember` method I'm essentially converting the return object into an `SafeExpandoObject` so if it's dereferenced again it will be sent back to the same method. Am I missing anything here in the overall implementation or are there any bugs or unforeseen situations?